# React Router caught the following error during render TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'posterPath' of 'location.state' as it is null

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I am using useLocation for transfer props to details route so I am getting this error
React Router caught the following error during render TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'posterPath' of 'location.state' as it is null.

How can I properly pass this data to the details route ? I want to display the data on details route when I click on the image of the Card component.

card component

```
const Card = ({ posterPath }) => {
return (
    <div className="pr-4 w-52 ">
    <Link to={{ pathname: "/details", state: { posterPath } }}>
    <img className= "w-44 hover:w-48 " alt="poster" src= {"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + posterPath}/>
    </Link>
</div>);
};

#details route
const MovieDetails = () => {
const location = useLocation();
const { posterPath } = location.state;
return (<div>
<img className="w-44 hover:w-48 "
alt="poster"
src={"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + posterPath}/>
</div>);
};
```

Comment: First remove this one
`const { posterPath } = location.state;`
Try to console log the location first and see what you getting in "state"

Comment: The code seems fine if you are using React-Router-DOM v5. If you are using v6 though the `state` is its own prop. See the duplicate for details.